# Bounds on variance and mean of maximum of difference of independent random variables

Tags: variance, mean, poisson-distribution, bounds, range

Suppose $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are independent but not necessarily identical random variables. $$Y = \max_{1\le i,j\le n}(X_i-X_j)$$
What upper and lower bounds can be derived for expectation and variance of $Y$?

The specific setting I am working on has $X_i$ distributed as Poisson random variable with mean/parameter $\lambda_i$. $\lambda_i$s may or may not be distinct. Any leads or specific answers for this case will be equally helpful.

Comment: This variable is related to "spacings".

Comment: @Xi'an Can you provide a reference?

Comment: In the formula for $Y$ did you intend to stipulate that $i\lt j$? If not, then why not use the simpler characterization of $Y$ as the *range* of the $X_i$? And if so, then on what basis have you ordered the $X_i$?

Comment: @whuber No the maximum is over all $i,j$. I did not know this was called the range.  Is there some known bound or exact formula for this case apart from the complicated ones on Wiki?

Comment: There aren't even nice formulas for the minimum or maximum of non-identically distributed variables.  Their distribution depends in a complicated way on *all* the distributions.

Comment: The full distributions of the extrema are relatively fast and easy to compute when the $\lambda_i$ do not get huge and there aren't an enormous number of them. Moreover, when those distributions don't overlap, they are nearly uncorrelated, allowing good estimation of the variance of the range.  Could you indicate more about the possible sets of $\lambda_i$ you are considering?

Comment: @whuber I am considering $\lambda_i = np_i$ where $n$ is a large number and $p_i$ form a probability distribution. Please let me know if there are any solutions to this. Even a partial solution under any assumptions you like would be great.

Comment: Could you please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only as comments. We want posts to be slef-contained, comments should be used for clarifications, ultimately leading to edits in the post! Also, comments are often seen only be few, and can be deleted!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application in mind, it might be possible to get some nice results useful for that application.

Meanwhile, here are the easy bounds from expressing $Y$ as $\max X_i - \min X_i$, which work for any non-negative distributions $X_i$ with means $\lambda_i$.

We can bound the extremes by:

$$\phantom{\max\max}0\le E[\min X_i] \le \min \lambda_i$$
$$\phantom{\max}\max \lambda_i \le E[\max X_i] \le \sum \lambda_i$$

So we can bound the expectation of $Y$ by:

$$\max\lambda_i - \min\lambda_i \le \ \ E[Y] \ \ \le \sum\lambda_i$$